# zsh history search put cursor at beginning of line by default

Tags: zsh

In zsh I use `set -o vi` and search through history by typing ESC-k or ESC-/searchterms and it works great!  When a line is located the cursor is at the end of the line.  But I prefer the cursor to be at the beginning of the line.  Is it possible to configure zsh to put the cursor at the beginning of the line?

I realize I can easily move to the beginning of the line with the 0 key.  But I would rather that the cursor be at the beginning of the selected line.